# SQL Server Linked Server Delete Won't Work

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an Oracle server linked in my SQL Server.  I am trying to DELETE all rows from a Table in the linked server and then repopulate the table with new data.  My insert queries work perfectly, but my delete either causes an error, or never completes.  Here are some of the methods attempted so far:

1: `SET @sql = N'BEGIN DB.SP_DELETE_TABLES(); END;' EXEC LS...sp_executesql @sql;`

2: `EXEC LS..DB.SP_DELETE_TABLES()`

3: `EXEC(' DELETE OPENQUERY('LS', ''SELECT * FROM DB.Table'')')`

4: `DELETE FROM LS..DB.Table`

5: `EXEC('DELETE FROM DB.Table') AT LS`

Is there a trick I am missing?  I let one of the ones that did not cause an error run for four hours before giving up and cancelling it (the table currently has one row, but I have tried all the methods listed with a variety of rows just in case).

Comment: What do your successful `INSERT`s look like?

Comment: They look like this: `EXEC(' INSERT INTO OPENQUERY('+@LS+', ''SELECT * FROM DB.Table'') (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE) (SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE from MyTable WHERE ColF= ''value'')')`